# Increasing the filesystem and partition size - vgdisplay "no volume groups found"

Tags: partitioning, lvm

I want to increase the main partition size on Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS server.
I'm trying to follow this guy's tutorial.

http://www.rootusers.com/how-to-increase-the-size-of-a-linux-lvm-by-expanding-the-virtual-machine-disk

At "Increasing the logical volume" step (I'm using sda2 instead of sda3):

```
root@Ubuntu:~# pvcreate /dev/sda2
Physical volume "/dev/sda2" successfully created

root@Ubuntu:~# vgdisplay
No volume groups found
```

So I'm stuck here. Next step is to extend the volume group, that you learn from vgdisplay command.

**EDIT:** Maybe I have to pvcreate /dev/sda1... according to this:

http://linuxconfig.org/linux-lvm-logical-volume-manager

But sda1 is my / partition, so I get "device is busy".

**EDIT:**
The output of df is:

```
/dev/sda1        16G  3.2G   12G  22% /
udev            487M  4.0K  487M   1% /dev
tmpfs           100M  220K  100M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            497M     0  497M   0% /run/shm
```

/dev/sda2 not visible here...

Comment: Are you sure you have installed ubuntu using lvm? What is the output of `df -h`

Comment: edit in a minute.. not sure how it was installed..

Comment: You can do this easily with gparted from a live cd/usb if you have the available space on your storage device. Do the answers for this question help?: http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions

Comment: it's a vm hosting with ssh access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not installed ubuntu using LVM partitioning.
If you had used LVM then `df` command should return something like

```
$ df -h
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/localhost--vg-root  7.0G  1.7G  5.0G  25% /
none                        4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                        232M  4.0K  232M   1% /dev
tmpfs                        50M  356K   49M   1% /run
none                        5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                        246M  4.0K  246M   1% /run/shm
/dev/vda1                   236M   75M  149M  34% /boot
```

Unfortunately there is no easy way to increase main partition. You could:

- Boot from some live-cd to redefine your partitions (Be careful of your data)
- Reinstall using LVM partitioning

[image]

Comment: damn... so reinstall the os than?

Comment: I am afraid it is the safest

Comment: You only have to re-install if you wish to implement LVM. If you want to use additional currently-unused space on the same storage device that your root partition already sits on, live cd plus gparted is a rather easy and simple way to go.

Comment: I will talk to the server guys tomorrow, but they will rather just reinstall the os... I don't have any important data for now..